# What is the total differential of z=ycos(xy)?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to figure out what dz/dy would be?
the derivative of dz/dx=-y^2 sin(xy)
I think dz/dy=-ysin(xy) but Im not sure.

Comment: you should be using the product and chain rules, just as if you were taking the derivative of $f(y) = y\cos(4y)$.

Answer (score 1):

If $x$ and $y$ are independent of each other, then $\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}y}$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d}x}$ are nonsensical.

$\mathrm{d}z$ always makes sense, however, and it can be computed simply by applying the derivative rules in the usual fashion (e.g. like you did in "implicit differentiation" problems):

$$ \begin{align} \mathrm{d} z &= y \mathrm{d} \cos(xy) + \cos(xy) \mathrm{d} y 
\\ &= -y \sin(xy) \mathrm{d} (xy) + \cos(xy) \mathrm{d} y
\\ &= -y \sin(xy) (x \mathrm{d} y + y \mathrm{d} x) + \cos(xy) \mathrm{d} y
\\ &= -y^2 \sin(xy) \mathrm{d} x + (\cos(xy) - xy \sin(xy)) \mathrm{d} y
\end{align}$$

If $x$ and $y$ are related, then for example, $\frac{\mathrm{d}z}{\mathrm{d} x}$ does make sense (so long as $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d} x}$ does), and is given by

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d} z}{\mathrm{d} x} 
= -y^2 \sin(xy) \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\mathrm{d} x} + (\cos(xy) - xy \sin(xy)) \frac{\mathrm{d} y}{\mathrm{d} x}$$

Answer (score 0):

to get $\frac {\partial z}{\partial y} $,

you will treat $x $ as a constant .

you will find

$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}=\cos (xy)-xy\sin (xy) $$

Comment: @Hurkyl Yes, thanks . done.